# Diffuse baking issue

Tags: texture-baking

I want to bake high-poly's texture onto unwrapped low-poly version, using Diffuse bake type. But it only seems to work around some of the vertices, as show on this picture:
[image: Diffuse baking issue]

The problem doesn't solve when trying higher Max Ray Distance...

Comment: hello what does it give if you increase the Extrusion value a bit? Because your mesh protrude a bit

Comment: Hello, thank you. Well with a value of 0.01 it only bakes on even less vertices.

Comment: You raise a point with my protruding mesh. Shouldn't I use a cage there maybe?

Comment: Extrusion should work but maybe pack your images and share your file?

Comment: Extrusion would work with a negative value imo, which is not possible..
I created a cage mesh from low-poly mesh and I finally have some result.

Comment: maybe your normals are inverted, hard to tell without the file

Comment: Not able to share it sorry ) But both objects have good Face Orientation.
I'd say logically the Extrude goes toward Normals direction, excluding what's behind in the baking.

Comment: Extrude allows to include the faces that are protuding, exactly like a cage

Comment: Ok, thank you @moonboots, I'll definitely look into the Extrude parameter, which would be way faster than reproducing a cage mesh.